# RXJS subscribe method not working when invoked from HTML Page

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to invoke a observable from the HTML page but it doesn't work. The method works as intended when *angular* invokes it and displays an output. But when I try to invoke it via a button, it doesn't work.

> Service

`deltasHistory = this.socket.fromEvent<any[]>('deltasHistory');`

> Component

```
constructor(private codeeditorservice: CodeeditorService){}
ngOnInit() {
this.deltaHistory$.subscribe(delta => {
      console.log(delta[30]); // Works perfectly
    })
}
```

Now this `invoke()` is initiated by `<button (click)="invoke()">Button</button>` but it displays nothing.

> Button inside the Component's HTML

```
  invoke(){
    console.log("invoking") // displays
    this.deltaHistory$.subscribe(delta => {
      console.log(delta[30]);
}) //nothing
  }
```

How do I fix the scope issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to update your service `deltaHistory` to return the last given result. You can do this by utilizing the [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator from rxjs:

```
deltasHistory = this.socket.fromEvent<any[]>('deltasHistory').pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Now any subscriptions done after the last emit, will get the last emitted value

Comment: Thank you so much!! It took me forever to understand what was going on.